# SkylineProblem in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented

### taken from [leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/the-skyline-problem/):

A city's skyline is the outer contour of the silhouette formed by all the buildings in that city when viewed from a distance. Given the locations and heights of all the buildings, return the skyline formed by these buildings collectively.
[...]
[image]

please review this code. I'm most interested in feedback about OOP-Principles (SOLID, readability, etc.) and second most interested on performance.

### class Solution

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[][] input = {{2,9,10},{3,7,15},{5,12,12},{15,20,10},{19,24,8}};
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        System.out.println("amount : "+solution.getSkyline(input));
    }

    //this crude method is a HARD REQUIREMENT and may not be changed!
    public List<List<Integer>> getSkyline(int[][] buildings) {
        SkyLineConverter skyLineConverter = new SkyLineConverter();
        SkyLine skyLine = skyLineConverter.convert(buildings);
        Set<Edge> edges = skyLine.getEdges();
        return sortList(edges);
    }

    private List<List<Integer>> sortList(Set<Edge> edges) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Edge> list = new ArrayList<>(edges);
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.x));
        for(Edge edge: list){
            List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
            intList.add(edge.x);
            intList.add(edge.height);
            result.add(intList);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

### class SkyLineConverter

```
public class SkyLineConverter {
    public SkyLine convert(int[][] raw) {
        BuildingConverter buildingConverter = new BuildingConverter();
        List<Building> buildings = buildingConverter.convert(raw);
        return new SkyLine(buildings);
    }
}
```

### class Building

```
public class Building {

    public final int x;
    public final int width;
    public final int height;

    public Building(int x, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

}
```

### class BuildingConverter

```
public class BuildingConverter {

    private static final int FROM_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int TO_INDEX = 1;
    private static final int HEIGHT_INDEX = 2;

    public List<Building> convert(int[][] raw) {
        List<Building> buildings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int[] buildingRaw: raw){
            int x = buildingRaw[FROM_INDEX];
            int width = buildingRaw[TO_INDEX] - buildingRaw[FROM_INDEX];
            int height = buildingRaw[HEIGHT_INDEX];
            buildings.add(new Building(x,width,height));
        }
        return buildings;
    }
}
```

### class Skyline

```
public class SkyLine {

    private final int width;
    private final Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<>();
    private final List<Building> buildings;

    public SkyLine(List<Building> buildings) {
        this.buildings = buildings;
        Building mostRight = findMostRight(buildings);
        width = mostRight.x + mostRight.width;
        addEdge();
    }

    private void addEdge() {
        buildings.forEach(b -> {
            addEdge(b.x);
            addEdge(b.x + b.width);
        });
        edges.add(new Edge(width, 0));
    }

    private void addEdge(int x) {
        int skyline = getSkyLine(x);
        int previous = x == 0 ? 0 : getSkyLine(x - 1);
        if (previous < skyline || previous > skyline) {
            edges.add(new Edge(x, skyline));
        }
    }

    private int getSkyLine(int x) {
        List<Building> aroundThisPoint = buildings.stream().
                filter(b -> b.x <= x && b.x + b.width > x).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
        return aroundThisPoint.stream().mapToInt(b -> b.height).max().orElse(0);
    }

    private Building findMostRight(List<Building> buildings) {
        Optional<Building> mostRight = buildings.stream().reduce((a, b) ->
                a.x > b.x ? a : b);
        //noinspection OptionalGetWithoutIsPresent
        return mostRight.get();
    }

    public Set<Edge> getEdges() {
        return edges;

    }

}
```

### class Edge

```
public class Edge {

    public final int x;
    public final int height;

    public Edge(int x, int height){
        this.x = x;
        this.height = height;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you have used stream library in most of your code, so I thought about increasing readability with less lines of code using streams if possible because other parts looks fine to me. In your `Solution` class you have the following method :

```
private List<List<Integer>> sortList(Set<Edge> edges) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Edge> list = new ArrayList<>(edges);
    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.x));
    for(Edge edge: list){
       List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
       intList.add(edge.x);
       intList.add(edge.height);
       result.add(intList);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could directly iterate over the `edges` set combining [`Stream#sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) and [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), so avoiding the need of explicitly instantiate a list like my method below:

```
private List<List<Integer>> sortList(Set<Edge> edges) {
        
   return edges.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(edge -> edge.x))
           .map(edge -> List.of(edge.x, edge.height))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());        
}
```

In your `BuildingConverter` class you have the following method:

```
public List<Building> convert(int[][] raw) {
    List<Building> buildings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int[] buildingRaw: raw){
        int x = buildingRaw[FROM_INDEX];
        int width = buildingRaw[TO_INDEX] - buildingRaw[FROM_INDEX];
        int height = buildingRaw[HEIGHT_INDEX];
        buildings.add(new Building(x,width,height));
    }
    return buildings;
}
```

It is possible streaming every row of your `int[][] raw` 2d array with [`Arrays#stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) and [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) obtaining the same expected result like below:

```
public List<Building> convert(int[][] raw) {

    return Arrays.stream(raw)
           .map(arr -> new Building(arr[FROM_INDEX], 
                                    arr[TO_INDEX] - arr[FROM_INDEX], 
                                    arr[HEIGHT_INDEX]))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In your class `SkyLine` you have the following two methods that can be simplified:

```
private int getSkyLine(int x) {
    List<Building> aroundThisPoint = buildings.stream().
           filter(b -> b.x <= x && b.x + b.width > x).
           collect(Collectors.toList());
    return aroundThisPoint.stream().mapToInt(b -> b.height).max().orElse(0);
}

private Building findMostRight(List<Building> buildings) {
    Optional<Building> mostRight = buildings.stream().reduce((a, b) ->
           a.x > b.x ? a : b);
    //noinspection OptionalGetWithoutIsPresent
    return mostRight.get();
}
```

In your `getSkyLine` method there is no need to instantiate an intermediate list that will be streamed, you can combine your code lines in a more succinct method:

```
private int getSkyLine(int x) {
        
    return buildings.stream()
            .filter(b -> b.x <= x && b.x + b.width > x)
            .mapToInt(b -> b.height)
            .max()
            .orElse(0);
}
```

Your `findMostRight` method could be simplified using the [`Collections#max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) like below:

```
private Building findMostRight(List<Building> buildings) {

    return Collections.max(buildings, Comparator.comparingInt(b -> b.x));
}
```

Comment: wow - java8 and streams are already so old and i still do not know how to use them properly - thank you very very much for these improvements!

Comment: @MartinFrank You are welcome, that also applies to me, I don't remember all the stream methods and without ide autocomplete I would be lost :-)

Comment: Thanks mdfst13 for the grammar corrections.